# Differentiation in Calculus

Tags: calculus

Let $r > 1$ be a rational number. Prove that for any $x \in [0, 1]$,

$$\frac{1}{2^{(r-1)}} \leq x^r + (1-x)^r ≤ 1 . $$

Must we use the extreme value theorem? or how do we go about proving this? is any differentiation required? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\,f\left(x\right)= x^r + \left(1-x\right)^r\,$ then
$$
f'\left(x\right)= r\,x^{r-1}-r\,\left(1-x\right)^{r-1}=0‎
\implies r\,x^{r-1}=r\,\left(1-x\right)^{r-1} 
\implies x=\left(1-x\right)
$$
will give $\,x=\frac{1}{2},\,$  $\,f'\left(x\right)>0\,$ for all $\,x>\frac{1}{2}\,$ and $\,f'\left(x\right)<0\,$ for all $\,x<\frac{1}{2}.\,$

Thus $\,\min f = f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{2^{\left(r-1\right)}}.\, $   Test $0$ and $1$ gives you $\,\max f=f\left(1\right)=f\left(0\right)=1$.